# Multiple emails with "to" and "CC" Alfresco 5.2

Tags: javascript, email, alfresco

We have a question for Alfresco 5.2
Using javascript (API) we want to send some emails for a CronJobs that we are developing.
We have seen that if we use "mail.parameters.to_many" we cannot send "CC".

We need to send

To: "email1@xxx.com", "email2@xxx.com"

cc: "email3@xxx.com"

If we use:

```
mail.parameters.to = "email1@xxx.com"
mail.parameters.cc = "email3@xxx.com"
```

we correctly receive the "to" and the "CC"

But if we use:

```
mail.parameters.to_many = ["email1@xxx.com", "email2@xxx.com"]
mail.parameters.cc = "email3@xxx.com"
```

We received in the "to" "email1@xxx.com", "email2@xxx.com" but "CC" empty.

How can you send multiple emails "to" with "CC"?
Example with "to" and "CC":

```
var subj= "prueva de multiples";
var mail = actions.create("mail");
mail.parameters.to ="email1@xxx.com";
mail.parameters.cc = "email3@xxx.com";
mail.parameters.subject = subj;
mail.parameters.from = "serverMail.com"; 
mail.parameters.text = "This test is OK";
mail.executeAsynchronously(node);
```

(Works correctlym It works fine, but a "to" and a "CC")

Example 2:

```
var subj= "prueva de multiples";
var mail = actions.create("mail");
var emails = ["email1@xxx.com","email2@xxx.com","email3@xxx.com"];
mail.parameters.to_many = emails;
mail.parameters.cc = ""email4CC@xxx.com";
mail.parameters.subject = subj;
mail.parameters.from = "serverMail.com"; 
mail.parameters.text = "This test is not Ok";
mail.executeAsynchronously(node);
```

(Sends the "to_many", but the "CC" does not send it)

We want to send multiple emails in "to" and multiple in "CC".

**The most important thing for us is to be able to send one "to" and multiple "CC"**

Thanks guys

Comment: Did you try setting a list of emails as the cc? https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/blob/master/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/action/executer/MailActionExecuter.java#L639 seems to suggest a list of cc emails should be supported on just the regular parameter

Comment: yes, I have tried a mailing list
var emailsCc = ["email2@xx.com", "email3@xx.com"];
Then in adding parameters:
mail.parameters.to = "email1@xx.com";
mail.parameters.cc = emailsCc;
It does not work.
I believe that the git code is of a version higher than the 5.2.2 that we are using.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source code for the MailActionExecuter and it looks to me like the CC param is only used if the TO is set (not the TO_MANY):

```
            // set recipient
            String to = (String)ruleAction.getParameterValue(PARAM_TO);
            String toRecipients = null;
            if (to != null && to.length() != 0)
            {
                messageRef[0].setTo(to);
                toRecipients = to;

                // Note: there is no validation on the username to check that it actually is an email address.
                // TODO Fix this.

                Serializable ccValue = (String)ruleAction.getParameterValue(PARAM_CC);
```

Based on that, I don't think you can use TO_MANY in combination with CC.

You can always just write your own action and have it work exactly like you need it to. You might start with the MailActionExecuter source to save some time.